# jquery Sticky Footer issue

Tags: jquery, footer, sticky

I have a problem with sticky footer, I mean exactly [this code](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/).

My example: http://jsfiddle.net/ecyZw/

The problem is that the footer isn't on the bottom of the screen (http://i39.tinypic.com/akzeva.png), my resolution - 1920x1080 px, BUT! when I remove top bar and header, the footer is at the bottom.

How can I make my footer appear at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Really don't understand so much what you want?

Comment: I want the #footer always at the bottom and margin between it and #wrapper, but as you can see, it does't work properly

Comment: Why you just use the:
`#footer{ background:#666; height: 146px; width: 100%; position: fixed; bottom: 0;}`

Comment: @vietean ... Are you in common with the crossbrowser situation with `position:fixed` ?

Comment: Yes. It is good for all of browsers, see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

http://jsfiddle.net/ecyZw/1/

You don't need to use the window scroll or resize event to update the footer, that just to do with:

```
#footer{ background:#666; height: 146px; width: 100%; position: fixed; bottom: 0;}
```

Comment: I know.. I could do in this way, but as I said earlier, i want margines between footer and div #wrapper, if I set position:fixed for footer it will overlap div #wrapper at smaller resolutions of screens